# How to get date of a year by using week and day in php?

Tags: php, date

I have a question to ask,

How to get date of a year by using week and day in php?

For eg if I have to calculate that what will be the date on thursday of week 46 of a given year, then how it can be done?

Comment: Since you haven't made an effort to solve the problem yourself, it seems that you are looking to [hire a paid freelancer to do it for you](http://www.freelancer.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate(2014, 46);
$date->modify('Thursday this week');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/190748)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following,

```
<?php  

function get_date_of_week($week_num, $day) {
  $timestamp    = strtotime(date('Y') . '-W' . $week_num . '-' . $day);
  return $timestamp;
}
$timestamp = get_date_of_week(46, 4);
echo date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);

?>
```